# I am having trouble saving programmatically created views in a fragment activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences, android-view

I have it set up so that user created views are saved via shared preferences. The information carries over fine, however when I try to recreate these views with the shared preference information the app crashes. The problem seems to be that the fragment is not fully loaded when my function to recreate the the views is called. However, I'm not sure where I should be calling load preferences to ensure that all the views have been inflated. I've tried onResume(), onStart(), and a few other possibilities and all result with the same problem.

My fragments are set up like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dice);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the two primary sections of the activity.

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_dice, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dice, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new fragment_dice();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new fragment_history();
                break;
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 2 total pages.
        return 2;

    }
}
```

Dice fragment java file:

```
public class fragment_dice extends Fragment {
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable 
ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dice, container, false);
    return v;
}
```

}

History Java File:

```
public class fragment_history extends Fragment {
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_history, container, false);
    return v;
}
```

}

Shared Preferences Functions:

```
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor = sp.edit();
    Log.d("test", "Save Size " + createdDiceNames.size());
    spEditor.putInt("Die_size", createdDiceNames.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < createdDiceNames.size(); i++) {
        spEditor.remove("Die_" + i);
        spEditor.putString("Die_" + i, createdDiceNames.get(i));
    }
    spEditor.commit();
}
public void loadPreferences() {
    SharedPreferences mSp = getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor = mSp.edit();
    createdDiceNames.clear();
    int size = mSp.getInt("Die_size", 0);
    Log.d("test", "Load Size " + size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        customDiceName = mSp.getString("Die_" + i, "").replaceAll(".+_","");
        for (int b = 0; b < createdDiceNames.size(); b++) {
            Log.d("test", "Array Value " + createdDiceNames.get(b));
        }
        Log.d("test", "Dice Name " + customDiceName);
        //This function is where the views are re-inflated and this is where the error occurs because the table layout has not yet loaded in the fragment
        createCustomDice();
    }
}
```

I have tried calling the load preference function with a button once the app has started to make sure it was working properly and it did. My question is where to put the function so that it loads only after the fragments views are loaded and does not cause it to crash.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using Shared Preferences, we need to see your logcat.

Anyway I think you might want to use a database. I suggest you using any schema-less (e.g. ObjectBox), but you should use any type. Shared Preferences are used for key-value objects (like preferences), but not for dynamically changing objects.

Comment: Even if I were to switch to a database wouldn't I still have the same problem of it loading in this data before the fragment has loaded, or do databases just work different from shared preferences in that way?

Comment: Kinda yes. While using SQLite, you define columns and every row can have different value. Then you use Cursor and go through all cells. On the other hand, schema free databases can be defined using objects, where you can have attributes that you then might want to join with viewmodel. Take a look here: https://docs.objectbox.io/entity-annotations